# fastest way to read multiple documents from Riak

Tags: php, linux, performance, riak

I have tried reading the documents in different format, I have an array of keys to use for reading. Each batch contains 1000 keys. I have 6 riak nodes. I do reads with r=1. I connect each time to the same riak node. Documents are just profile fields, so it's not something big. I've checked the CPU and disk usage on the nodes, and I can observe just a slight move, but not even close to overall 20% CPU.

Method 1: `multiGet` ([code section linked here](https://gist.github.com/pentium10/5567d38d9670f0ffecdb)):

```
$data = $riak->multiGet($ids); /*EXECUTION TIME 80seconds*/
```

Method 2: `key_filter` ([code section linked here](https://gist.github.com/pentium10/d00d3d94bdc8be85220f))

```
$data = $riak->multiGetBetween($id1, $id2); /* GIVES RIAK INTERNAL TIMEOUT*/
```

Method 3: one by one `get`

```
foreach ($ids as $key) {
    $riak->get($key);
    $data[$key] = $riak->document->data;
} /* EXECUTION TIME 20seconds */
```

As you see the method 3 is the better, but the problem I have with all of them, is that I cannot run more than `2 threads`. If I try to run more, I get socket timeout connection. I checked the linux open limits and it's 240k. I ran out of options what to try and do here. Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianRoach can you help on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach for retrieving multiple objects is to use multiple connections in order to parallelise the work and connect to all available nodes in order to spread out the load. This has the benefit that it returns all the object data as well as the metadata and results in a quorum read and read-repair being performed. The load can also be spread out across the cluster. It however works best for clients that have good support for concurrency and/or threading.

For client libraries that do not, a common approach is to try to perform multi-GETs as a MapReduce job. This is a reasonably heavyweight way to query data and requires Riak to set up and execute the MapReduce job. Running large amounts of concurrent MapReduce jobs can therefore put a lot of load on the system. It also does not result in a quorum read and read-repair will not be triggered.

This is what you are doing in the method 2 example. If you know the keys you wish to retrieve, it would however be more efficient to specify these directly rather than use a key filter as Riak has to scan a lot less objects. If you are using the LevelDB backend, you could also base your query on a secondary index lookup. In your example I also noted that you are using a JavaScript Map function. This is considerably slower than using Erlang functions and uses a pool of JavaScript VMs that are specified in the app.config file. There is an Erlang function available that returns the object value, and I believe the map phase for this should be specified as `map(array("riak_kv_mapreduce", "map_object_value"))`.

Some time ago I did experiment a little with creating MapReduce functions that return all the important data of Riak objects, e.g. indexes, metadata and the vector clock. The results are encoded as JSON, which means that these functions are limited to data that is valid JSON. The functions and some simple examples and documentation can be found [in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/cdahlqvist/json_multiget). Please note that this has not been tested extensively. I have so far also not gotten around turning the resulting output into Riak objects for the client libraries that could benefit from it.

Another way to get around the issue of having to retrieve large number of objects from Riak is  to de-normalise the data model in order to ensure common queries can be served through a smaller number of requests. This is the approach I generally recommend as it generally scales well. If you have data that is read-heavy, it usually makes sense to do a bit more work when inserting or updating data in order to ensure the data can be read efficiently. Exactly how this can be done will however depend a lot on your data and you access patterns.

Comment: I am querying based on indexes, so I cannot normalize more here. I thought mapReduce will be extremely fast when only keys are used. I do use multiple connections as I run 2 threads. Each thread iterates over  separate 1k keys. Since I have 2 threads, it's multiple connections. When I setup the 3rd thread I get connection timeout issues from Riak. So what can you say specific for my issue?

Comment: Which backend are you using? Can you provide some additional details on your data model and access patterns?

Comment: You can specify input to MapReduce as the result of a secondary index query if you are using LevelDB. This would probably be more efficient than using key filters as you do in method 2. In order to speed the method 2 approach up further I would recommend using a map phase function implemented in Erlang. e.g. https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/develop/src/riak_kv_mapreduce.erl#L96, for returning the values.

Comment: I use riak_kv, what additional data model and access patterns are you referring too?

Comment: With access patterns I am referring to read/write ratio for your data as well as how you typically query the data. The backend you are using is also interesting as it determines whether secondary indexes are available or not.

Comment: Read/write ratio usually is 1:1 as the primary "search" source is Sphinx, and we don't quite query riak, only by key, to get the full document. We use riak_kv.

Comment: If that is the case it may not make any sense de-normalising.

Comment: Which backend are you using? Do you have siblings enabled?

Comment: I am doing something wrong here, I already told two times I use riak_kv. Isn't that a backend? Correct me if I am sending you wrong information. I do not have any siblings, but how would I check for their presence?

Comment: There are 3 available backends: LevelDB, Bitcask and Memory. Which one(s) you are using is defined in the app.config file. These have different properties that may affect which way to best retrieve data in your case. Whether you have siblings enabled or not is defined by the `allow_mult` bucket property. By default this is set to `false`.

Comment: Any idea for improvement?

Comment: Revised my answer with some suggestions. I would modify your method 2 example to use the available Erlang function `map_object_value' instead and if possible specify the keys rather than use a key filter to see of that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a load balancer between your PHP application and Riak, I would recommend using HAProxy to ensure your application does not connect to just one Riak node.

Riak works best when requests are spread out evenly among all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: We have that in place, but even with that we have speed problems using just one node.

Comment: With multiGet and keyStream connection is made only to one node, but as you see it's way to slow.